# Fixed Data Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, reactjs

I'm looking for examples about Fixed-Data-Table.

https://facebook.github.io/fixed-data-table/

I want some of these specialities:

-Add,Delete or Update Rows.

-Editable Cells.

I couldn't find docs about these specialities.Can you suggest any doc or example?

Answer (score 1):

In this doc here: http://facebook.github.io/fixed-data-table/#basic-example

You'll notice that the `rows` object is an array of data that the table takes.  If you store this in your component's state (or, even better, in a data store like Redux), the table should update automatically when you add, remove, or update that row from the array.  The table itself doesn't offer you any of this functionality because it's outside of the scope of the project.  All that it does is handle rendering lots of data efficiently and present it nicely so you don't have to worry about the CSS.

In short, you'll have to add the functionality to operate on the underlying data that the table depends on.

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of using a fixed data is that you can manipulate the entire table on an array or an object.

I am assuming that you are working on React. It would have been good if you would have mentioned that.
Consider the following code

```
`
<Table 
    rowHeight={40}
    rowsCount={this.state.data.length} //source of the table
    width={900}
    height={300}
    headerHeight={50}
/>
  `
```

the rowsCount would be equal to the number of entries in 'data'.
To increase the row on a button click

```
`<Button onClick={this.handleClick}`
```

this would add a new row to the table and since the render method is called whenever there is a setState, the new row gets added on the table.

```
`handleClick=()=>{
    this.setState({data:[...this.state.data,[]]})
}`
```

The same principle is applicable for Delete. You just have to remove the index and do a setState.